# Should this sentence end with a Question mark or period?

Tags: punctuation

If you'd like one of the above times, let me know?

Comment: What are your arguments for both?

Comment: It depends entirely on if you're asking a question or making a statement. (It could also end with an exclamation mark if it's phrased as an order)

Comment: No, if your voice doesn't go up when you say it, it probably doesn't need a question mark. If it does, though, it would sound like a rhetorical question and I'd use!? This fits well, since you have in principle an embedded question (to which the one question mark belongs) and an imperative (to which the bang belongs), hence your wonderment. It would help if you'd actually phrase it like a question (using e.g. *which*). The weird things is that the if-clause could be seen as a dependent clause, and the matrix-phrase is imperative. If the phrase is imperative, use an exclamation mark?!

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether this is meant to be spoken or written, there should be a period at the end (at least I believe so). This is because the words are not questions, they are instructions, statements.

Your statement can be separated into two parts:
[If you'd like one of the above times], [let me know].

Question words include: will, who, what, when, where, why, how, is, can, are, do. 'If' is not a question word, it indicates a condition, if A, then B. Your condition is, there is a selection of times, on the chance/condition that one of them suits you, then do B, let me know what that time is.

If you wanted to turn it into a question, you can say something like:
"If you'd like one of the above times, CAN you let me know [please, ASAP]"
"Are there any times that suit you?"

Comment: Question words are not strictly needed to form questions. Tone usually is significant enough, I'd argue that the first clause could have a raising tone. So the question could be equally "*(You) let me know if you would like one the above times?*" with "let" in the subjunctive. But: If clauses do by convention not need a subjunctive "would", so that "would" would have to go in the dependent clause. Since it is but where it is, it must be a past tense form, and whether "like" is an archaic subjunctive or not remains indecisive.

Comment: @vectory
I've seen people write thing exactly like that, where they end a (usually non question) phrase with a question mark, exactly like "Let me know if you would like one the above times?". This sounds very awkward as a question, especially when you try an read it in a question tone yourself. The only time I feel such a use of a question mark and tone is when the non-question sentence is said as a suggestion, like A: "Then what do you suggest I do?" B: "Ask him to let you know if he would like one the above times?"

Answer (score -1):

Is this intended to be and written as a question?

If not, how and why would a question mark appear at the end?

The answers to the above two questions will determine when (and whether) a question mark is the proper punctuation at the end of a sentence.

Is it clear that your sentence needs a question mark at its end?

(The sentences in this answer hopefully illustrate the point, don't they?)

Comment: It's simply two disparate sentences, if you will: "*You'd like one of the above times? Let me know if!*"